# Embedded images are not displaying in Outlook app on ios

Tags: ios, iphone, email, outlook, html-email

I have a html email which contains a footer image (as an attachment of the html email), which is implemented as follow:

```
&lt;img width=&quot;600&quot; height=&quot;151&quot; style=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;cid:email_footer&quot; alt=&quot;My Company&quot;&gt;
```

It works perfectly on Gmail, Apple Mail (ios and mac), and Outlook on my PC. However, the image simply doesn't show in the Outlook app on my iPhone! It only shows the alt-text. How can I resolve this problem?

EDIT: the email displayed fine if it is forwarded from somewhere else.

EDIT-2: looks like it's only a problem with image as attachment. It loads remote images just fine...

EDIT-3: Based on the answer, my investigation leads to the result of adding the following line and it works on all the above email clients/apps now :)

```
 bodyPart.setDisposition( MimeBodyPart.INLINE);
```

Comment: I think this isn't because of your code. It's probably because of some configuration the outlook app has. Do other images display on the app?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how those images are embedded. And interestingly, the email displays just fine if it is forwarded from somewhere else.

Comment: well how important is it then that the one image is displayed in Outlook for iPhone? Do you have data of how much of your audience is using Outlook for iPhone? I would guess that it isn't that relevant if just a tiny percentage wont see the one image. Maybe your better off styling your alttext ti make it half decent

Comment: try playing around with the mimetype for the CID-based attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-ID` MIME header on the attachment to `email_footer`.

Comment: In my case, I need to add ` bodyPart.setDisposition( MimeBodyPart.INLINE);`